# A question about principality of ideals dividing $(p)$ in imaginary quadratic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, pell-type-equations

Exercise 8 of chapter IX.3 of Cohn's book Advanced Number Theory reads:

Show that if the fundamental discriminant $d = g_1 g_2 < 0$ satisfies $(g_1/p) = (g_2/p) = -1$ for a prime $p$, then the divisors of the ideal $(p)$ in the number ring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ are nonprincipal.

This is equivalent to showing that the diophantine equation
$$4p = x^2 + |g_1g_2| y^2$$
if $d \equiv 1$ mod $4$, or
$$p = x^2 + |g_1g_2| y^2$$
otherwise, has no integer solution $(x, y)$.

If $p$ is odd and $d \equiv 1$ mod $4$, quadratic reciprocity leads to $p$, $g_1$ and $g_2$ being $\equiv 3$ mod $4$, but I am not sure how to obtain more information from the sign of the Legendre symbols. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that makes clear what's going on. Let $d = -3 \cdot 5$; then
$(-3/17) = (5/17) = -1$. This implies that $p$ splits in $k$; reducing the equation $4 \cdot 17 = x^2 + 15y^2$ modulo $5$ implies $(17/5) = +1$: contradiction by the quadratic reciprocity law.